# Luarocks breaks after installing luasocket

Tags: lua, luasocket, luarocks

Running Arch Linux here, lua version is 5.1, luarocks 2.0.12

After running `luarocks install luasocket` I can't install any more packages. The error message I'm seeing is

```
Warning: Failed searching manifest: Failed loading manifest: Failed fetching manifest for http://www.luarocks.org/repositories/rocks - Error fetching file: Failed downloading http://www.luarocks.org/repositories/rocks/manifest - closed
Warning: Failed searching manifest: Failed loading manifest: Failed fetching manifest for http://luarocks.giga.puc-rio.br/ - Error fetching file: Failed downloading http://luarocks.giga.puc-rio.br/manifest - closed
Warning: Failed searching manifest: Failed loading manifest: Failed fetching manifest for http://luafr.org/luarocks/rocks - Error fetching file: Failed downloading http://luafr.org/luarocks/rocks/manifest - closed
...
```

So looks like installing luasocket somehow breaks luarocks. I searched for it and one guy seemed to have a similar problem on Windows, and he seems to have resolved it by removing the luasocket dll (huh?).

Has anyone else had this problem? Is there a fix?

Comment: That thread you mention deals with an issue regarding proxies. Is that your case?

Answer (score 0):

Luarocks is written in Lua and uses luasocket itself, so there may be an incompatibility. Luarocks uses luasocket 2.0.2. I find it strange that Luarocks would break this way; you might want to file a bug, or at least contact the [mailing list](http://www.luarocks.org/en/Mailing_list).